# How to define vertical spacing around subcaptions

Tags: spacing, captions

I want to increase the spacing between my (sub)figures and their respective captions. Unfortunately, all things tried (skip or margin options in e.g. \captionsetup, vspaces) didn't have any effect.

What is the correct way to do so?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup{ 
%  heightadjust=noobject,
%  valign=b
%}
\captionsetup{skip=-50pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\ffigbox[\textwidth]{
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][\FBheight]
    {\caption{a}}
    {\rule{14cm}{7cm}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][\FBheight]
    {\caption{b}}
    {\fbox{\rule{7cm}{4cm}\vspace{20pt}}}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth][\FBheight]
    {\caption{c}}
    {\rule{7cm}{4cm}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{cap}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use `floatrow`? `subcaption` offers `subfigure` feature by itself.

Comment: Isn't subfigure outdated?

Comment: `subfigure` package is outdated. `subcaption` provides `subfigure` environment.

Comment: okay- but for some reason (maybe some special alignment) I've chosen floatrow foŕ my project...

But does the treatment of spacing differ so much between them?