# Adjusting vertical spacing in subfloatrow captions (subcaption+floatrow)

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

I am trying to adjust sub-captions for sub-figures in a figure which includes multiple `\subfloatrow`s and an additional `\ffigbox` outside the rows.

How can I modify the vertical spacing between sub-figure and sub-caption and between sub-caption and any sub-figure below it? I would like the sub-caption to be closer to its sub-figure and a little further from any sub-figure below it.

[image: sub-figures in rows with sub-captions]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[valign=c,heightadjust=all]{floatrow}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfloatrow]{font+={footnotesize}}%
  \floatbox{figure}{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \ffigbox{%
      \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\subcaption*{Sub-Caption}}
  }{%
    \caption{Caption}\label{fig:label}%
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[Guntram's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138732/how-to-define-vertical-spacing-around-subcaptions) is similar, but it has not be answered in over 2 years. The suggestion in comments is to abandon use of `floatrow`. However, this is supposed, I think, to work with the `caption`/`subcaption` packages. At least, so the documentation says.

However, I don't find `floatrow`'s documentation at all easy and I cannot really figure out how `caption`-`subcaption`-`floatrow` are intended to play nicely together.

Answer (score 5):

Controlling vertical spacing between rows is well hidden in the documentation: you have to declare a key via`\DeclareFloatVCode`, and ask to apply it with`\floatsetup{rowpostcode= …}`. Font size can be changed via `\captionsetup[subfigure]`, ang the vertical skip between figure and caption is settled with `\floatsetup{captionskip= …}`.

Here is a (hideous) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe, margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[,heightadjust=all]{floatrow}

\DeclareFloatVCode{largevskip}%
{\vskip 20pt}
\floatsetup{captionskip=0pt,rowpostcode =largevskip, valign=c }%
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font =Large}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering-%
  \floatbox{figure}{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
      \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
        \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\caption*{Sub-Caption}}
    \end{subfloatrow}

    \ffigbox{%
      \includegraphics[height=8em]{example-image-a}}{\subcaption*{Sub-Caption}}
  }{%
    \caption{Caption}\label{fig:label}%
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solves half of the problem. I can add more space underneath the sub-captions and that's great ;). But I can't reduce the distance between the sub-figure and the sub-caption. (The `skip=-10pt` you have looked promising but doesn't seem to make any difference. [I hope you don't object to my edit - I got very confused when it kept claiming the macro you'd named was undefined!]

Comment: Why did you need `xcolor`? I'm loading it in my real document, but I omitted it from the MWE.

Comment: I have to admit I noticed `\DeclareFloatVCode` in the documentation. But I could not figure out what to do with it. It is not the most intuitive interface. More a scenic route.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I messed up with an old code of mine. Probably I was doing two things (writing two codes?) at the same time. Probably I fing those example images very dull. I removed it.

Comment: No problem. Was just curious. If I add `\captionsetup[subfigure]{font+={footnotesize},skip=2.5pt}%` then this does affect the non-floatrow `\subcaption*` by reducing the distance between it and its sub-figure. But I can't figure out how to do the same for those in the `subfloatrow`. Is `subfloatrow` the correct type of caption?

Comment: I agree with you ; it's not evry intuitive and often not really well documented. Furthermore some codes in the examples result in errors when tested. I remember having noticed  some  routines don't work because they call . macros that aren' t defined. Makes me think of an unfinished project…

Comment: @cfr - Does it help if you adjust the `floatrow`'s with something like `\floatsetup[subfigure]{
  captionskip=10pt,
  rowpostcode=captionskip}` and for the `subcaption` with `\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=10pt}`?

Comment: Found it! I need `\thisfloatsetup{rowpostcode=extraskip,midcode=extraskip}` and then `\captionsetup[subfloatrow]{...}` and `\captionsetup[subfigure]{...,skip=2.5pt}` ...?

Comment: @ArashEsbati I think it is `midcode` I want.

Comment: @cfr - I was more looking at the skip between the `\subcaption*` and the figure above it which looks less than between `\caption*` and figures in those `subfloatrow`-env's.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Yes, you're right. With my modification, that disappears. But now the overall figure caption seems too close to the stuff above it.

Comment: Right now, I've got `\usepackage[valign=c,heightadjust=all]{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatVCode{extraskipbelowsubfloatrow}{\vskip 2.5pt}%
\begin{document}
\thisfloatsetup{rowpostcode=extraskipbelowsubfloatrow,midcode=extraskipbelowsubfloatrow}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \captionsetup[subfloatrow]{font+={footnotesize}}%
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{font+={footnotesize},skip=2.5pt}%
` which reduces the distance to the overall figure caption. This is better, but non-ideal, I think. Also @ArashEsbati

Comment: While I was trying to test various solutions to the other problems, I see you didn't lose your time!  I've updated my answer, as you have noticed.

Comment: Thanks. That still doesn't look right to me. There's more space before the final sub-caption but it doesn't seem possible to reduce it without reducing the space between the final sub-caption and the overall figure caption. I found `subfloatrow*` in the manual, too. That simplifies the configuration, but it doesn't actually seem to improve the situation. [Not that I do not greatly appreciate your help - floatrow just seems... recalcitrant.]

Comment: @Bernard http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27790928#27790928

Comment: So the solution would lie in the `midcode` key.  I noticed it, and found the `captionskip ` key more meaningful , but didn't notice the problem with the last caption.

Comment: You'd think. But every time I get one element right, another one goes wrong. I really don't like `floatrow`... and its documentation, I like that even less :(.